# Resizing Image code in python also reading script file

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I have written a script for resizing images using Python Imaging library. Code is working fine but script is also reading .py script file. How can I avoid that?

```
import os 
import sys
import PIL
import PIL as pillow
from PIL import Image
from resizeimage import resizeimage

opts, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], 'd:w:h:')
filepath = r'C://python27//test'
saved = 'C://python27//test2'
basewidth = 4193
for opt, arg in opts:
    if opt == '-d':
        filepath = arg
    if opt == '-w':
        basewidth = int(arg)

if basewidth == -1 or filepath == '':
    print('Invalid command line arguments. -d [directory] ' \
          '-w [width]  are required')
    exit()

for image in os.listdir(filepath):
    print('Resizing image ' + image)
    name,ext = os.path.splitext(image)
    if ext.lower() in [".png", ".jpg", ".bmp"]:
        img = Image.open(image)
        width = (basewidth / float(img.size[0]))
        height = int((float(img.size[1]) * float(width)))
        img = img.resize((basewidth, height), PIL.Image.ANTIALIAS)
        img = resizeimage.resize('crop', img, [3000, 2800])
        img.save(os.path.join(saved, 'resized-' + image))
```

**Output:** 
  `Resizing image 852A9961.JPG 
  Resizing image pc1.PNG
  Resizing image try13.py`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you have to move the line `print('Resizing image ' + image)` inside the `if` codeblock. That way it'll print the message only when a file was processed and not for every file in the directory.

Just for stylistic reasons, in the line `for image in os.listdir(filepath):` you should change the word `image` for file, since conceptually at that point you have generic files in that list. Only after the `if` statement you are kinda sure you have an image that you can process.

Comment: Thank you very much it worked . Can i ask one more thing related to this post or i have to make a new question?

Comment: Probably better a new question.